# TPL Dataflow, notification when data block received first item

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, dataflow, tpl-dataflow

I wonder whether it is possible to subscribe to a one-time notification when the first item is  received in the input buffer or processed in a data block. I am aware I can set a flag within the data block but that would create overhead as it would run check the flag on each new item. My data block processes several million items thus this flag adds unnecessary overhead.

Is there a better way to be notified on the first incoming item?

Comment: Maybe connect the input buffer to `BroadcastBlock`, which will then link to your main dataflow and to [`WriteOnceBlock<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194820.aspx)? The `WriteOnceBlock` will only get written once (first item)...

Comment: Are you really saying that checking a single `bool` is unnecessary overhead? I doubt that. Have you tried measuring this?

Comment: Hmm, definitely a neat idea, using WriteOnceBlock. I use Broadcast Block anyway, so that should work. I guess I do not have to handle subsequently rejected messages because items are streamed through a broadcast block, correct?

Comment: @svick, I have and as I iterate over around 17 million messages (the data blocks handle batches of such messages but internally each batch is iterated over.) on each run, any if condition adds overhead. Now one can argue whether it is significant or not. I measured it and if I can shave off 200-500 milliseconds on the complete run then it is worth it.

Comment: @svick, but I see where you may point to, possibly that I look at the wrong technology implementation and should rather look for a C++ solution if latency/throughput matters that much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a link with MaxMessages=1 to a block that processes the notification. This link would be removed after delivering a single message.

Comment: But for normal blocks, this would mean that only this block would receive the notification, the regular target wouldn't.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. You could have the notification block pass the message on to the regular target, but that might mean the messages get reordered. Or you could work around this with a broadcast block, which is supposedly already in place in this case.

Answer (score 1):

(I know this is 11 months too late ... but I'm answering in the hope that someone will tell me why this isn't a good idea.)

You have a particular block X where you want to know when it gets its first message.  It has an upstream block.  Insert between the upstream block and block X a TransformBlock, linking it from the upstream block with MaxMessages=1 so that it gets immediately unlinked when it gets the first message.  That also blocks the upstream block.  The inserted TransformBlock's Func does 3 things in its delegate:

1. Does whatever notification you'd like that the "first block was received".
2. Links its successor block X to the upstream block.
3. Returns its argument unchanged to get passed to block X.

In other words ... the inserted block accepts and passes on the first data item and is spliced out of the dataflow.